# How to set value of checkbox in listview based on select query in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

I want to set the value of the checkbox in my listview based on my select query when I click the button,

I have a column MARK that has checkbox, and in my select query I have a field MARK with the values of T and F, what I want is if the field is T then the checkbox will have a check, if F then the checkbox is blank.

Here is my code of select query:

```
SELECT A.`MARK`, A.`BRNCH_CODE`, A.`NAME`, B.`NAME` as LABEL_NAME, A.`DEPT_CLASS`, A.`CO_CODE`, A.`CO_DESC`, A.`BR_CODE`, A.`BR_DESC` FROM `branch` as A INNER JOIN `label` as B ON A.`LABEL_CODE` = B.`LABEL_CODE`"
```

I'm using vb.net and mysql, Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say you **select an item =(0)** in listview and want the text in **second column = (1)**

```
listView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
```

Comment: Hi Ali, I ust edited my question, what I want is to automatically set the values when I click the button, tnx

Comment: what do you mean by connecting it to mysql?

Comment: the sql selected item will be displayed in listview box, which you can reach by the code above.

Comment: i just want to ask is the code you give is when I click in the listview? tnx